# Creating Spray Routes in Java

Tags: spray

I am trying to add spray routes in Java instead of scala.  So far I have figured out to extend HttpServiceActor, but how do one maps the path?

For example,

```
http://xxx:8080/file/123
```

How to create a path for "file" here mapped to HttpGet?  It's pretty straightforward in scala, but I am struggling with finding the right API in java.

Comment: That will be very hard to do because of all the Scala features spray uses. The upcoming successor of spray, akka-http, will feature a Java routing API which is currently under development (see [this PR](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/16308) for the progress).

Comment: That said, you may be able to use the (much less convenient) spray-can level API to write a service in Java depending on how much features you need. You need to be able to write an actor in Java that handles an `HttpRequest` similar to how you would do in Scala as described here: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/http-server/#basic-architecture